# how to find a word starts with . and ends with ; in large file and after save that file a corresponding table name. hql

Tags: python

input file 
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test.employee ( eid int, name String,salary String, destination String)
COMMENT ‘Employee details’
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ‘\t’
LINES TERMINATED BY ‘\n’
STORED AS TEXTFILE;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test.employee1 ( eid int, name String,salary String, destination String)
COMMENT ‘Employee details’
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ‘\t’
LINES TERMINATED BY ‘\n’
STORED AS TEXTFILE;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test.employee2 ( eid int, name String,salary String, destination String)
COMMENT ‘Employee details’
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ‘\t’
LINES TERMINATED BY ‘\n’
STORED AS TEXTFILE;
......so on

expected output:

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test.employee ( eid int, name String,salary String, destination String)
COMMENT ‘Employee details’
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ‘\t’
LINES TERMINATED BY ‘\n’
STORED AS TEXTFILE;

save it as employee.hql
and CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test.employee1( eid int, name String,salary String, destination String)
COMMENT ‘Employee details’
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ‘\t’
LINES TERMINATED BY ‘\n’
STORED AS TEXTFILE;

save it as employee1.hql
and so on.....
I tried with re, for me, it's possible only either capture the table name or else ends with data. Unable to join both re-expressions. Am new to python. Help me how to achieve this.

Comment: What re did you use? Now what are you trying to do in python are you creating table using python if so what is your code? You ve to provide details about these in order to make others understand the problem clearly.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how big your input file is but here is one solution:

```
import re
sql_file = "sql.txt"

with open(sql_file) as f:
    data=f.read().replace('\n', '')

    items = data.split("; ")
    for item in items:
        if item: # skip blank lines
            sql = item + ";" 
            table_name = re.findall(r"(\w+\.\w+)", sql)
            if table_name:
                _, outfile = table_name[0].split(".")
                outfile += ".hql"
                print("Writing:", outfile)
                with open( outfile, "w") as f:
                    f.write(sql + "\n")
```

Essentially, it reads in the while sql input, then it splits on a **;** followed by a space. If you have any other semicolons, you would need to modify this to be a little less brittle.

Next, it looks at each item, and looks for a letters, period, letters. Then it splits it, and takes the second part, which is your table name, to be used as the filename.

Last, it writes the SQL out and gives it a filename as you described.

Answer (score 0):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
text = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test.employee ( eid int, name String,salary String, destination String) COMMENT ‘Employee details’ ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ‘\\t’ LINES TERMINATED BY ‘\\n’ STORED AS TEXTFILE; CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test.employee1 ( eid int, name String,salary String, destination String) COMMENT ‘Employee details’ ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ‘\\t’ LINES TERMINATED BY ‘\\n’ STORED AS TEXTFILE; CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test.employee2 ( eid int, name String,salary String, destination String) COMMENT ‘Employee details’ ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ‘\\t’ LINES TERMINATED BY ‘\\n’ STORED AS TEXTFILE;"
for item in re.findall(r'CREATE[^;]*;',text):
    print 'Save in',re.search(r'(?<=\.)\w+',item).group()+'.sql'
    print item
```

Not very clear but this may help you.